# How to loop through this?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Using the URL below.

http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?region=US&lang=en-US&query=google

I am getting the following ...

```
{  
   "ResultSet":{  
      "Query":"Google",
      "Result":[  
         {  
            "symbol":"GOOG34F.SA",
            "name":"GOOGLE      DRN A",
            "exch":"SAO",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Sao Paolo",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {  
            "symbol":"^VXGOG",
            "name":"CBOE EQUITY VIXON GOOGLE",
            "exch":"WCB",
            "type":"I",
            "exchDisp":"Chicago Board Options Exchange",
            "typeDisp":"Index"
         },
         {  
            "symbol":"GOOG34.SA",
            "name":"GOOGLE      DRN A",
            "exch":"SAO",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Sao Paolo",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {  
            "symbol":"GOOG35.SA",
            "name":"GOOGLE      DRN C",
            "exch":"SAO",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Sao Paolo",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {  
            "symbol":"GOOG35F.SA",
            "name":"GOOGLE      DRN C",
            "exch":"SAO",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Sao Paolo",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How do I loop through it to get the symbol and name of each? I am using node.js on server. Tried following ...

```
var request = require('request');
var _ = require('lodash');
var url = "http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?region=US&lang=en-US&query=google";

request(url, function (error, response, data) {

if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

var textToOuput = 'Results\n\n';

_.each(data.ResultSet.Result, function(i, Result){  
  textToOutput += "Symbol: "+Result.symbol+", Name: "+Result.name+"\n");
});

}

});
```

But get following error:

```
_.each(data.ResultSet.Result, function(i, Result){
                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Result' of undefined
```

Comment: I am totally sure that `data.ResultSet` is undefined. Log your `data` and check what's inside it.

Comment: Do a `console.log(data)` and look at what it outputs.

Comment: console.log(data) looks like what I posted.

Comment: So what type the `data` variable is?

Comment: variable type is string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because the type of data is string, not a object. you can use `JSON.parse(data)` to convert it to an object first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through data

```
var _getResult = _myObject.ResultSet.Result;
    _getResult.forEach(function(item){
    document.write('<pre> Symbol --'+item.symbol+' Name --'+item.name+'</pre>')
    })
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/3e2798Lh/)

Comment: I tried but get error at same location.  

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Result' of undefined`

Comment: @MorningSleeper first you can check by consoling data that is console.log(data). If you can see the log then there wont be any problem but if not then probably you are not getting the response

Comment: thanks, I could see the log but it is a string and needed to be converted into an object, then your code worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is full working code, just keep it in any node application, install request and lodash packages (npm install) it will print you name and symbol as expected.

```
Below corrections added in your code -
1) You need to parse string into json (JSON.parse(data)
2) textToOutput was undefined, corrected variable name.
3) in look call back function, 1st arguments is current item or object of running iterator , and 2nd param is index.
```

Final output (as per current result )-

```
Results
Symbol: GOOG34F.SA, Name: GOOGLE      DRN A
Symbol: ^VXGOG, Name: CBOE EQUITY VIXON GOOGLE
Symbol: GOOG34.SA, Name: GOOGLE      DRN A
Symbol: GOOG35.SA, Name: GOOGLE      DRN C
Symbol: GOOG35F.SA, Name: GOOGLE      DRN C
```

Working code :

```
var request = require('request');
var _ = require('lodash');
var url = "http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?region=US&lang=en-US&query=google";

request(url, function (error, response, data) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200 && null !== data) {
        var resultJsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        var textToOutput = 'Results\n\n';

        _.each(resultJsonData.ResultSet.Result, function (curItem, i) {
            textToOutput += "Symbol: " + curItem.symbol + ", Name: " + curItem.name + "\n";
        });
        console.log(textToOutput);

    }
});
```